# why inline view is different from other views?what is the use of naming it as a view

Tags: oracle, view, inline

As i know inline view is not a database object and it is just like writing a sub query in from clause so what is the use of naming it as a view .Simply we can call as a sub query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Oracle naming convention. From [Inline View](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Inline_view) and [Subquery](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Subquery):

> **An inline view is a SELECT statement in the FROM-clause of another SELECT statement. In-line views are commonly used to simplify complex queries by removing join operations and condensing several separate queries into a single query.**
>
> This feature is commonly referred to in the MSSQL community as a **derived table**, and in the Postgres community simply refers to it as a subselect (subselects are inline views + subqueries in Oracle nomenclature).
>
> **A subquery (sub-query) is a SELECT statement in the WHERE- or HAVING-clause of another SELECT statement.**

So when you used it with `FROM` it is called `inline view`:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ( SELECT deptno, count(*) emp_count
         FROM emp
         GROUP BY deptno ) emp,
       dept
 WHERE dept.deptno = emp.deptno;
```

And when you used it with `WHERE`/`HAVING` it is called `subquery`:

```
SELECT ename, deptno 
  FROM emp 
 WHERE deptno = (SELECT deptno 
                   FROM emp 
                  WHERE ename = 'TAYLOR');
```